# Overlapping <div>'s with an image on a wrapper

Tags: html, css, image, styling

I know this question has been answered but I am having extreme difficulty using the answers given before and applying them into my code.

I am making an tab-pane with different images. I want to put the image in the lighter orange section on the right with the text on the left. However, this tab is placed onto a wrapper and it's confusing me with the indexes.

In addition, all the solutions that work without considering the wrapper doesn't work when I use XXAMP.

Below is what I have so far and applies to the description :

[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
  background-image: url(../media/style/background.jpg);
  font-family: helvetica;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

#wrapper img {
  width: 80%;
  height: 60%;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20;
  margin-left: auto;
  height: auto;
  border: medium none #9C0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.images {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab-content {
  width: 825px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  border-right: 2px solid white;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 2px solid white;
  padding: 13px;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-tabs {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  width: 805px;
}

.tab-content {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(245, 172, 64, 0.9);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1) 50%, #F4B350 50%);
  min-height: 300px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.tab-content img {
  position: relative;
  width: 58vw;
  height: 42vw;
}

.container a {
  background-color: rgba(245, 172, 64, 0.9);
  color: black;
}

.tab-content p {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.tab-content h3 {
  font-size: 28px;
}

#tab1 h3 p {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Hanler Products - Home</title>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- TAB -->

  <div class="container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab1">Upright Towbar Caddy</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab2">Upright Trailer lid Caddy</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab3">Park Stand</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab4">Gates / Burglar Bars / Security Gates</a></li>
      <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab5">Fences</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <div class="box">
          <h3>Upright Towbar Caddy</h3>
          <p>Ideal for short trips to school and back.</p>
        </div>
        <img src="media/style/slider/UTC.jpg" alt="Upright Towbar Caddy">
      </div>
      <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Upright Trailer lid Caddy</h3>
        <p>Now, taking your cycles on holiday, is a breeze.</p>
        <img src="media/style/UTC.jpg" alt="Upright Trailer lid Caddy" />
      </div>
      <div id="tab3" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Park Stand</h3>
        <p>Ideal for parking bikes at shops, schools and at shopping malls.<br/>The parkstand could prevent damage to vehicles <br/> in parking areas.<br/>The bike could also be chained to be stand <br/> to protect it from being stolen.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab4" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Gates / Burglar Bars / Security Gates</h3>
        <p>Custom security bars to keep you and your belongings safe.</p>
      </div>
      <div id="tab5" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Fences</h3>
        <p>Custom fencing for your home and/or business.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pulling the text to the left, like this;

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <div class="box pull-left">
```